# Change password of other user in using devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used devise gem for authentication. There are multiple users and i am admin. I want to change the password of other users. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You can use the update method from rails console. `User.find(user_id).update_attributes(password: "password")`

Comment: I have tried that but in users table there is no column named password.

Comment: The password that a user types is encrypted by Devise and that encrypted value is stored. The password should not be stored directly as it would expose the value to who can access the database.

Comment: there will be column named encrypted_password, which stores the encrypted password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a better way but you can implement an action which passes the new password typed in a form field and do the following. The code below will work in the rails console as well.(tested on Device 4.2.0)

```
u = User.find(user_id)
u.password = "changed_password"
u.save
```

EDIT:
**I would strongly suggest to rethink doing this**. How would the existing user know what his password is. Alternative - you may also build a mechanism so that users can use the forgot password method and set their password themselves. To do so you can make the encrypted_password null and send them a forgot password email(with appropriate message in the mail that their current password has expired and they need to set a new one) so that they can use it to set their password themselves.

Comment: I have confidential data and i want to give the username and password to the users. and if i feel that someone is going to reveal my data then i can change their password.

Comment: You don't need `password_confirmation` just `password` will do